# HTC Device not listed when i change the connection type

Tags: java, android

I am using HTC wild fire for android development. I have a small doubt. Does connection type matter when we try to run the app on eclipse with the device.For me, in run configurations, device is shown only if the connection type is disk drive. If i select Internet pass through then it, does not show. 
All these days it appeared to me that connection type does not matter. I believe it should work just by enabling the debugging options.Should i change any other setting to make it appear on the list of devices in eclipse?

Comment: what do you mean by "Internet pass through"?!! if you mean Internet tethering, then it may be the problem, because in that mode, your phone acts as a modem and connection to "adb" may drop, and when SDK does not find your phone through "adb" then it does not show your phone in the list.

Comment: Internet pass through means it helps me connect to pc's internet connection..

Answer (score 1):

Connection type needs to be set to charge only.